# How I can simulateneously sort and unique files from directory using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sort and unique 30 files of different sizes in one single file.
Each file contains a single line and are separated by newline. That means the file has simple text on each single line.
Here is what I tried to attempt:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open('out.txt', "w")
for line in open('d:\\testing\\*', "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

The folder name is `testing` and it contains 30 different files, which I am trying to combine into file `out.txt`. The output will be the sorted and unique text, written on each line of the output file.
Well, I thought it would be easy, if I write `d:\\testing\\*` and it will read the files from the folder. But I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort and unique.py", line 3, in <module>
    for line in open('d:\\testing\\*', "r"):
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'd:\\testing\\*'
```

I would like to know how I can get rid of this error and process my all files efficiently into one single output without any unsuccess.
Please note:  RAM is 8 GB and the folder size is about 10 GB.

Comment: the star syntax needs shell expansion. The `glob` module can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop over all files using `os.listdir`. Something like this:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open('out.txt', "w")
path = r'd:\testing'
for file in os.listdir(path): #added this line
    current_file = os.path.join(path, file)
    for line in open(current_file, "r"):
        if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
            outfile.write(line)
            lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Let me try... I will get back to you

Comment: Is it possible to make the program multi-process or multi-thread, so that it will be faster?